# iOS: How to import multiple 'open app action' for ios theming

Tags: ios, iphone, theming

Since apple deprecated the option to use the `TargetApplicationBundleIdentifier`to launch apps with custom icons by using webclip, I'm wondering if there is a solution to import multiple `open app` actions to theme the home screen?
As far as I know, I can import new shortcuts shared by icloud, but is there a better solution? Probably by using a mobileconf file or anything like that?